# rails custom rest route with parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a questions controller and an associated model and a number of rest routes.  Here is how it's set up in routes.rb:

```
resources :questions
```

I want to add a custom route that has the format /questions/widget/ID (where ID is the id of the question for which I want to generate a widget).  I want this to be processed by the "widget" action in my questions controller.  I've tried a number of things such as:

```
resources :questions  do
   member do
      get 'widget/:id'
   end
end
```

But nothing is working.  I'm sure I'm missing something simple.  Any ideas?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do not have to specify the id since you are inside resources. It should look like:

```
resources :questions  do
   member do
      get 'widget'
   end
end
```

You can get more information from the [Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html). Look at section 2.9.1.

Edit: I just noticed that you are trying to match get /questions/widget/:id. This will set up a route for get /questions/:id/widget. This is more in line with Rails convention. If you really want it the other way, you need to set up a custom match statement:

```
match "/questions/widget/:id" => "questions#widget"
```

However, I would stick with convention.

Comment: Thanks.  But if I try something like question_widget_url(@question), I get an "undefined method" error.

Comment: If you look at the guide section, it tells you that Rails generates the :method_:resource_(url/path) helpers. In your case, that would be widget_question_(url/path).

Answer (score 2):

I know it is old, but looking to fix another routing problem I ended here, it is possible, to do what you are asking for, here is an example

```
resources :articles do
  get 'by_tag/:tag' => :by_tag, on: :collection
  get 'by_author/:author' => :by_author, on: :collection
  resources :comments, except: :show
end
```

now you have /artices/by_tag/:tag . The trick was to use on:collection.
Obviously don't forget to add the by_tag action and by_author.

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
.....
    def by_tag
    ...
    end
end
```

Check this route works with

```
melardev@local~$ rails routes
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use this routes:

```
resources :questions  do
  resources :widgets
end
```

it will create path like `questions/:question_id/widgets/new` for you to create new widget for question with specific id of question.

Answer (score 0):

This is what ended up working for me:

```
resources :post do
  get "author/:author", to: "posts#author", on: :collection, as: "author"
end
```

Which outputs the following route:

```
author_posts   GET /posts/author/:author(.:format)       posts#author
```

Then in your controller, you need to create the author action:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  def author
    @roles = Post.where(author: params[:author])
    render :index # to reuse the index view
  end
end
```

Then in your view:

```
<%= link_to post.author, author_posts_path(post.author), data: { turbo_frame: "_top" } %>
```